# What is the definition of the contraction $\iota_\wedge (e)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be vector space and let $\wedge V$ be the exterior algebra of $V$.

If $e \in V$, what is the definition of the operator which is called the contraction by $e$ : $$\iota_\wedge(e): \wedge V \rightarrow \wedge V$$

Comment: You are missing some duals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define $\iota_\wedge(e):\Lambda^p(V)\to\Lambda^{p-1}(V)$ by
$$
\iota_\wedge(e)\omega(x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1}) = \omega(e,x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1}).
$$
Then extend this to $\Lambda(V)$ by linearity.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm a little confused because if $\omega$ is an element of $\wedge^p(V^*)$, then it has entries in V, just like you worked with $\omega$ element in $\wedge^p (V)$. Could you please elaborate further in this point.

Comment: If $\omega \in \Lambda^p(V)$ then $e,x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1}\in V^*$ and if $\omega \in \Lambda^p(V)$ then $e,x_1,\ldots,x_{p-1}\in V^{**}$ or $\in V$. Which one doesn't matter much since $V \hookrightarrow V^{**}$.